# Common divisors

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Prove that the following statement is true:

For all positive integers $a$ and $b$, if $a \neq 1$ and $a \neq 5$, then $3a \nmid  (4b-1)$ or $a \nmid (12b + 7)$.

Comment: Formatting note:  "\nmid" looks better than "\not |".  $n\nmid m$ versus $n\not | m$.

Comment: To your question, note that $12b+7=3(4b-1)+10$ and since both are clearly odd, we must have $\gcd(4b-1, 12b+7)\,|\,5$.  And both $1$ and $5$ are possible.

Comment: Why must we have $\gcd(4b-1, 12b+7) | 5$?

Comment: Since the gcd divides $10$ and must be odd.

Comment: Sorry, can you write down a full proof and break down your logic a little more?

Comment: Just try it yourself.   What I'm saying comes down to: if $n=m+c$ then $\gcd(m,n)\, |\,c$.